# D3 animation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications, d3.js

I have a button that when pressed begins a color change transition in D3 for 1.5 seconds. The issue is that if someone presses the button again while the transition is taking place, the animation starts from the beginning again. Is there any way to deal with this? Even if I have a variable indicating that an animation is taking place, the variable is changed to false even before the animation is completed. Even then, I wouldn't know where to place the variable

```
if (animation !== "false") { ??????
d3.select("#" + element.id).transition().attr("fill", "#fffff").duration(animationDuration)
}
```

Comment: Well it is not a nice solution, but have you tried to remove the listener from the button? Then set it again with an timer event triggered after `animationDuration`.

Comment: That's should be good enough to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener for the `end` event using the `each` function that will tell you when a transition has finished. In the handler for that you can either set your variable that tells you if a transition is taking place or, as suggested in the comment, reenable the listener. More in the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-each).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you might use .each() and end. Here a sample syntax:

```
    element.id.transition(1500)
        .attr('fill', '#ffffff')
        .each('end',function() {   
            // event handler will start after the end of previous 
            transition       
        });
```